# ESRI unable to load image from localhost

Tags: javascript, nestjs, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to redirect my ESRI-request from my frontend via my backend to the ESRI-endpoint.

If i do so, i get the following error:
[Unable to load Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65g1I.png)

I tried changing the url-endpoint direct to the arcgis api, instead of redirecting via localhost.
This way it works, but that's not what i wanted to do.
Even tho the URL of the image looks fine, but the one from arcgis is perfect and the other one (with exact same url except localhost instead of arcgis-url) does not work.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?
Request Headers looking fine so far...

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to proxy the services through your backend, right?. If that is so, what are you using to do it?

Comment: exactly! i'm just calling a get-request on localhost/arcgis/rest/* and every request seems to work, except for the image.

Comment: are you using `esriConfig.request.proxyRules`?

Comment: @cabesuon no, what are those for?

Comment: Hi @Timmy sorry the delay in the response .. So the API has a set of tools in order to help this kind of situations, `proxyRules` is one of those .. check this link [ArcGIS API - config request](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-config.html#request) .. also take into account there are different ways to implement proxies, I think that with the REST API most of the ways should work but does not do bad to check how ESRI propose it, [ArcGIS - Proxy](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/proxies/index.html#steps-to-working-with-the-proxy)

Comment: Hi @cabesuon i tried so hard, but i'm not getting there... what do i have to set the proxyRules to? i tried the normal URL i want to make the request to

Comment: Hi @Timmy sorry I've been super busy las weeks .. Trying to remember, you install one of the proxy applications and then use the proxyRules, right? .. Can you add to the post the proxy config of the proxy app, the proxy rules of the library, and the url of the endpoint?

Comment: @cabesuon no problem, don't worry :) i am actually setting up my own backend to use it as a proxy.. i want to redirect the request from my frontend via my backend to esri/arcgis. then i should get an image from esri to my backend and the backend should return it to my frontend, but there it failes with the postet error.

Comment: the reason for this is, because i can't access the esri-url from outside a specific network, thats why i need that proxy-thing

Comment: I understand .. follow this guide [ArcGIS - Proxy](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/proxies/index.html#steps-to-working-with-the-proxy) .. on step 2 just set the proxy for the require service using `urlUtils.addProxyRule` .. let me know the result

Comment: i tried setting the proxyRules like the esri docs say.. nothing changed :(

Comment: this is meant to do in the frontend, right?

Comment: yes that goes in the frontend, can you add the proxy rules both backend and frontend?

Comment: unfortunately not, frontend only

Comment: how you doing with the backend part?

Comment: i guess we made it: we had to use a package from esri to convert the response from a blob-file an image.. anyways, many thanks for your support!

Comment: Glad you figure it out!